# put a page break when specific chracter found in visual force

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud

on a repeat tag one-field name "insurance__c" is populating some description.
on this field contents are having bullets. I wants to put a page break after when a bullet will come.
like this:- (single break after single Description)

• Description1 

• Description1

• Description1

but this is coming as a paragraph (without a break) on the PDF

Comment: remark:- this VF page is generating as PDF. (renderedAs="pdf")

Comment: What happens if you just insert some new lines (\n), any love?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean page break or line break.

You can usually achieve this using the `<div>` or the `<br>` element(for linebreak) and CSS.

```
<br clear="all" style="page-break-before:always" />
```